# Установка pecl_http на Apache под Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: php, apache, debian, kohana, apache2

Для установки фреймфорвка Kohana 3.3.4 пытаюсь установить модуль PHP pecl_http.

Делаю всё по [мануалу](http://php.net/manual/ru/http.install.php), плюс искал информацию на форумах и на англоязычном SO, но пока что так и не удалось решить проблему.

При установке выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr' failed
```

Все необходимые зависимости, упоминание которых нашёл в Сети, я установил.

Модули propro и raphf поставил:

```
user@host:~$  ls /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ -l
total 1392
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89240 Oct  4 19:23 curl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114200 Oct  4 19:23 gd.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 384200 Oct 22  2014 imagick.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39696 Aug  1  2014 json.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48072 Oct  4 19:23 mcrypt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 155560 Oct  4 19:23 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60504 Oct  4 19:23 mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160344 Oct  4 19:23 opcache.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  32072 Oct  4 19:23 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 122440 Oct  4 19:23 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60440 Dec  8 11:40 propro.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  74248 Dec  8 11:40 raphf.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31576 Oct  4 19:23 readline.so
```

В php.ini (`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`) добавил подключение модулей:

```
extension="propro.so"
extension="raphf.so"
```

Apache естественно перезапускал.

Версии используемого ПО:

- 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u5 (2015-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
- PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:13:10)
- Zend Engine v2.6.0 with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev

Вот полный вывод команды `pecl install pecl_http`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
downloading pecl_http-2.5.5.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-2.5.5.tgz (199,782 bytes)
..........................................done: 199,782 bytes
71 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
where to find zlib [/usr] :
where to find libcurl [/usr] :
where to find libevent [/usr] :
where to find libidn [/usr] :
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root6ByQNB/pecl_http-2.5.5
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/p                                                                         hp5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable extended HTTP support... yes, shared
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for mbstate_t... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking wctype.h usability... yes
checking wctype.h presence... yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for mbrtowc... yes
checking for mbtowc... yes
checking for iswalnum... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for idna.h... not found
checking for idn2.h... not found
checking unicode/uidna.h usability... no
checking unicode/uidna.h presence... no
checking for unicode/uidna.h... no
checking for icu-config... no
checking for uidna_IDNToASCII... checking for zlib.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8
checking for curl/curl.h... found in /usr
checking for curl-config... found: /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for curl version >= 7.18.2... 7.38.0
checking for HTTP2 support in libcurl... no
checking for SSL support in libcurl... yes
checking for OpenSSL support in libcurl... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking openssl/crypto.h usability... yes
checking openssl/crypto.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/crypto.h... yes
checking for GnuTLS support in libcurl... no
checking for NSS support in libcurl... no
checking for SecureTransport support in libcurl... no
checking for GSKit support in libcurl... no
checking for ares support in libcurl... no
checking whether CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_TYPE expects CURL_TLSAUTH_SRP or literal "SRP"... "SRP"
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking for event2/event.h... found in /usr
checking for libevent version, roughly... 2.0.21-stable
checking for ext/raphf support... no
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr' failed
```

Чувствую, что ответ где-то близко, но туплю и не могу понять где я ошибаюсь...

Пожалуйста, помогите :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При установке выдаёт

не знаю, что именно вы подразумеваете под «установкой», но подозреваю, что вы запускаете при этом интерпретатор *php* напрямую, без *apache*.

следовательно, ручные изменения вам надо вносить не только в `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, но и в `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

хотя правильнее, конечно, было изменять не эти два файла, а создать файл с нужными строками в каталоге `/etc/php5/mods-available/`, а затем «включить» его с помощью скрипта `php5enmod`.

Comment: Отлично, помогло добавление в `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, спасибо большое! Так и думал, что "истина где-то рядом"... Файл в `/etc/php5/mods-available/` присутствует, спасибо за рекомендацию по поводу `php5enmod` - сейчас сделаю как правильно.